# trying to import and index data from mysql to apache solr but got exception

Tags: indexing, solr, dataimporthandler

I am very new to apache solr. I installed apache solr with the help of google and youtube. I made a core and made solrconfig.xml, schema.xml, data-config.xml, but when I went on the solr admin page and run the data import command it shows an exception.

Error-> "mycollection: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to use updateLog: *version* field must exist in schema and be searchable (indexed or docValues) and retrievable(stored or docValues) and not multiValued (*version* does not exist)". I also provide the lib dir of data import handler and provide the version but still problem remains the same. mycoolection is the name of the core that I made. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Add **version** field to your managed-schema.xml.

```
<field name="version" type="float" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Reload the Configuration and then run the dataimport command.

Comment: Thanks. One more problem, I tried to index from database. First i got error to add lang/stopwords_it.txt, after adding it I got

Comment: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'my': Unable to create core [my] Caused by: Input length = 1, i don't have any idea about this error.